# In a three-phase circuit, do all three phases connect to the same bus or are there three separate buses?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bus, busbar

Below is a per-phase representation of a small power system from *Power Systems Analysis* (Grainger and Stevenson, p206).

I'm trying to imagine the three-phase version of this circuit diagram. Let's take the connection between bus 1 and bus 2 as an example. Presumably, we would draw three line segments between bus 1 and bus 2. **Would we also need to draw three buses at 1 and three buses at 2?**

I've heard that any given bus will have associated with it just one voltage. I'm confused about how to reconcile this hearsay with the notion that, in a three-phase system, three lines with different voltages would be connected to the same bus (unless there are actually three buses?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are three separate lines (busses), one for each phase.

- In a Delta system, there are just these three lines (X, Y, Z)
- In a Y system, there's also a fourth line, for the neutral (N)

In practice, there's one more line: earth (E)

More info: https://www.belden.com/blogs/3-phase-power-wye-it-matters

[image: Y, delta]

Comment: Thanks Davide. So you are confirming that there is in fact a separate bus for each phase, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct...